# how do i get 5 dates of current week with php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, date

i have this and yesterday it worked fine, but not today.

```
$current_dayname = date("l");    
$datemon = date("m-d-Y",strtotime('monday this week'));
$datetue = date("m-d-Y",strtotime("tuesday this week"));
$datewed = date("m-d-Y",strtotime("wednesday this week"));
$datethu = date("m-d-Y",strtotime("thursday this week"));
$datefri = date("m-d-Y",strtotime("friday this week"));
```

yesterday, $datemon through $datefri would get the values of 1-20-2014 through 1-24-2014, but today only tuesday through friday is working and monday is getting the date for next monday, not yesterday.

how can i get the dates of the 5 weekdays of the current week?  so if it's wednesday for example, the 5 variables should be 2 for 2 days past, 1 for current day, and 2 for future days.  know what i mean?

i'm going to guess that someone will ask if week starts with monday or sunday.  doesn't really matter as long as script works, but the week starting on a monday is preferable.

Comment: `monday this week` outputs `string(10) "01-20-2014"` for me.

Comment: hm, `'monday this week'` still gives me yesterday's date.  Perhaps a locale difference?

Comment: maybe you can use the format of '+ days' like strtotime( '+1 days' );

Comment: maybe set the default timezone: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier way to get those dates might be something like this:

```
$today = time();
$wday = date('w', $today);   
$datemon = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 1)*86400);
$datetue = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 2)*86400);
$datewed = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 3)*86400);
$datethu = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 4)*86400);
$datefri = date('m-d-Y', $today - ($wday - 5)*86400);
```

I would also recommend using an array instead of 5 different variables, but that's a separate concern.

Answer (score 0):

Simple [`DateTime::setISODate()`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.setisodate.php) example:

```php
$dt = new DateTime();
$dates = [];
for ($d = 1; $d <= 5; $d++) {
    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'), $d);
    $dates[$dt->format('D')] = $dt->format('m-d-Y');
}
print_r($dates);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [Mon] => 01-20-2014
    [Tue] => 01-21-2014
    [Wed] => 01-22-2014
    [Thu] => 01-23-2014
    [Fri] => 01-24-2014
)
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/92980)</kbd>